# node.js app server needs a companion file server

Tags: node.js, azure, fileserver

I'm running node.js as my app server and it has been working great for most of my needs. I big part of my application is uploading and downloading media files to the Server.

The functionality I need is close to what Amazon S3 or Azure blob storage offers - allow thousands of files to be uploaded and downloaded every hour (multiple servers are OK). The ability to authenticate the user before allowing upload/download. The URL/URI I wish to use for download/upload will include the session key, filename and the expiration of the link.

I do not see how this can be accomplished using NGINX. Any guidance on what is the best platform for this download/upload requirement will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As here is a glance of Scalability targets for azure storage blobs:

- Total Request Rate (assuming 1KB object size) per storage account
  --Up to 20,000 IOPS, entities per second, or messages per second
- Target throughput for single blob
  --Up to 60 MB per second, or up to 500 requests per second

These features should satisfy your requirement. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/ for more info about Azure Storage Scalability and Performance Targets.

And in your applications, you can leverage SAS token of Blob storage, to can grant a client limited permissions to objects in your storage account for a specified period of time and with a specified set of permissions.

For example, you provide an SAS URI of your blob for your user download in its browser, your user will directly request to the Azure Storage server and download the blob. Which will also can shared the access workload of your web service. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/ for details.

At last, you can use Azure Web Apps to host your node.js application, which also provides multiple features, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-overview/ for more info.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have used Azure and Amzon in the past and they work great. The question I posted is for another application where I cannot keep the information on a public Cloud, it needs to stay in-house in our data center.

Comment: Did you solve your question? Or could you please clarify your requirement?

Comment: I ended up using node.js for file transfer. upload and download both.

To clarify, I'm looking for an answer to the question "what is the most efficient method for file transfer (upload and download), when upload and download are allowed only when the client is authorized to transfer the said file." This is similar to what Amazon, Google or Azure (with its blobs) does, the difference being I want this Server to run on my infrastructure and not on Cloud providers infrastructure.